# zipWith function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

```
ghci> zipWith' (zipWith' (*)) [[1,2,3],[3,5,6],[2,3,4]] [[3,2,2],[3,4,5],[5,4,3]]
```

The function zipWith' use function '*' and parameters after it to get the return.But in this case,how the function zipWith' to get the result [[3,4,6],[9,20,30],[10,12,12]] .

The code example using zipWith' was taken verbatim from the free online book [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions).

Comment: do you mean `zipWith`, or did you make your own custom method called `zipWith'`

Comment: CathyLu, are these just homework problems? If you want to know how a particular function works in Haskell, try [Hoogle] first. (http://haskell.org/hoogle)

Comment: @Dan: I think these problems, at least this one, are coming from [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions#higher-orderism)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`zipWith` calls the given function pairwise on each member of both lists. So `zipWith f [a,b,c] [x,y,z]` evaluates to `[f a x, f b y, f c z]`. In this case `f` is `zipWith (*)` and the elements of the lists are again lists, so you get:

```
[ zipWith (*) [1,2,3] [3,2,2],
  zipWith (*) [3,5,6] [3,4,5], 
  zipWith (*) [2,3,4] [5,4,3] ]
```

Now the inner calls to `zipWith` multiply the elements of the inner lists pairwise, so you get:

```
[ [3,4,6],
  [9,20,30],
  [10,12,12] ]
```